# change CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR

Tags: cmake

In my **CMakeLists.txt** I can easily change **`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`**:

```
set(CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qqq )
```

From now on, I will see the new value in all CMake statements, functions, etc. But this does not effect file lookup. The following statement still works

```
add_library(t SHARED qqq/rrr.cpp)
```

while this fails:

```
add_library(t SHARED rrr.cpp)
```

Is there a way to relally *change* the **`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to really *change* the `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`?

Use `add_subdirectory(qqq)`.

Seriously, `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` denotes location of the `CMakeLists.txt` which is currently processed. Some CMake functions (even internal ones) heavily rely on this property of the variable. This variable **should NOT be changed manually**.

---

All variables which refers to `SOURCE` or `BINARY` directories should be treated as **readonly**. Among them:

- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR
- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR
- CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR
- CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR
- <PROJECT-NAME>_SOURCE_DIR
- <PROJECT-NAME>_BINARY_DIR
- PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR
- PROJECT_BINARY_DIR

Comment: I cannot `add_subdirectory(qqq)` without adding the file **qqq/CMakeLists.txt**, can I?

Comment: Yes, `add_subdirectory` implies that you have `CMakeLists.txt` in corresponded source directory.

Comment: which means, I cannot achieve my humble goal 

Comment: It depends on your "humble goal" :)

Comment: all I want is to be able to use a 3rd-party source directory without poisoning it with **CMakeLists.txt**.

Comment: Hm, and what is wrong with `add_library(t SHARED qqq/rrr.cpp)` which is works for you? (You may update your question post with **actual problem** you want to solve. So, instead of solving XY problem, we can concentrate on your actual one.)

Comment: now imagine that it's not `qqq`, but rather `d:\repo\deep\inside\some\3rd\party\git\submodule`… I don't want to look for these **.o** files in 20 levels of subdirectories.

Comment: Store that path in the variable (say, `THAT_SUPER_LIB`), and use variable for refer to that path: `add_library(t SHARED ${THAT_SUPER_LIB}/rrr.cpp)`. If there are many source files in the 3d-party library, you may collect them using `GLOB`. Or store  their filenames in the variable, and iterate over this variable (using `foreach()`) for create list of absolute paths to the source files.

Comment: *Store that path in the variable* – sure, it is a variable, and the **CMakeLists.txt** itself looks not that bad. What I want to clean up, though, is the path to *object files on disk*: this inflates my logs, makes debugging harder, especially when sometimes it is built on Windows, and other times on Linux. My deliverables contain hardcoded paths on the build machine. Not nice. 

Comment: "My deliverables contain hardcoded paths on the build machine." - As far as I know, this is unrelated to the *sources*' paths, whether they relative or absolute. The similar is about paths to objects files on disk: they depends on **build directory** and on the location of the source files, but not from the *current source directory*.

Comment: I see the paths of object files relative to the **build directory**, and that's file. Normally, this is something like `CMakeFiles/Proj.dir/rrr.cpp.o` or in case of few **add_subdirectory()**, `subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/CMakeFiles/Proj.dir/rrr.cpp.o`. But this case creates `subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/CMakeFiles/Proj.dir/D_/repo/deep/inside/…`

Comment: So, path to the objects files depends on paths to source files... Which **build tool** do you use (Makefile, Visual Studio, etc.)? Not all CMake generators (corresponded to the build tool) generate such paths for the object files. Other generators leave only a filename, but append unique digit string in case of same source filenames located in different directories. It seems that XY problem becomes closer to X than Y...